# How to vertically align text in the middle of two divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to vertically align `+` symbol in the middle of the `boxes` div however I can't get it working. What am I doing wrong? I would also like to avoid using tables. Thanks ( I also attached codepen link)

```
<div class="boxes">
   <div class="boxes_box">
   </div>
   <div class="boxes_plus">+</div>
   <div class="boxes_box">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxes {
  height: 250px;
}
.boxes_box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#000;
}
.boxes_plus {
  display:inline-block;
  height:250px;
  line-height:250px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aoiGm

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I would like to avoid tables first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the smallest change from what you have, change `.box_plus`'s `vertical-align` to `top`.

http://codepen.io/jwhitfieldseed/pen/FeJco

Explanation: `line-height` puts the "+" text in the vertical center of `.boxes_plus`.

The text is already centred vertically in its container, so you now need to make the top of `.boxes_plus` align with the top of `.boxes_box`.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to understand what it does exactly

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
.boxes {
  height: 250px;
  display:table;/*Add display table*/
}
.boxes_box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#000;
  display:table-cell;/*display table cell here is not necessary*/
}
.boxes_plus {
  display:inline-block;
  height:250px;
  line-height:250px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:table-cell;/*Add display table cell*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cea6qhgg/1/)

Alternative you can simple remove `line-height`:

```
.boxes_plus {
  display:inline-block;
  height:250px;
  /*line-height:250px;*/
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cea6qhgg/4/)

Comment: anyway to do it without tables? (forgot to mention that, sorry)

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
.boxes {
  height: 250px;
  display:table;
}
.boxes_box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display:table-cell;
  background:#000;
}
.boxes_plus {
  display:table-cell;
  height:250px;
  line-height:250px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I was about to suggest exactly the same thing my friend! >:3

Answer (score 2):

Please update your css as follow

```
.boxes {
  height: 250px;
  display: table
}
.boxes_box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display:table-cell;
  background:#000;
}
.boxes_plus {
  display:table-cell;
  height:250px;
  line-height:250px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/crBea

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/uZMjfsom1a)

```
.boxes {
  height: 250px;
  display:table;
}
.boxes_box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#000;
}
.boxes_plus {
  display:table-cell;
  height:250px;
  line-height:250px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```